# HTML Display images on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML page with an image(wanna use as a button) and some several images that I set to be invisible by CSS visibility: hidden. I want to make when i click this 'image 'w-click.png'' another several image appear.

so,  tag to some other images. In my case, I want the click 'w-click.png' to invoke a JavaScript to display the images.

i found one click one image appearing, but i want one click several images appearing....

edit : this is my code

```
<img src="IMAGE/w-click.png" style="z-index:200; margin-left:6680px; position:relative; width:700px; margin-top:-100px; padding:0; position:absolute; " />

    <div class="invisible-livingroom">
        <img src="IMAGE/w-clock.png" style="position:absolute; margin-left:1200px; filter:brightness(1.3);visibility:hidden; " />
        <img src="IMAGE/w-stand.png" style="position:absolute; margin-left:1830px; margin-top:120px;filter:brightness(1.2);  height:800px; z-index:5; visibility:hidden;"/>
        <img src="IMAGE/w-cushion.png" style="position:absolute; margin-left:1450px; margin-top:270px; transform:rotate(2deg); visibility:hidden;"/>
        <img src="IMAGE/w-light.png" style="position:absolute; margin-left:1310px; width:900px; margin-top:-130px; filter:brightness(0.95); visibility:hidden;" />
        <img src="IMAGE/w-livingroom-table.png" style="position:absolute; margin-left:1310px; width:900px; margin-top:240px; filter:brightness(1.6); visibility:hidden;"/>
        <img src="IMAGE/w-frame2.png" style="position:absolute; width:300px; margin-left:1500px; margin-top:120px; visibility:hidden;"/>
    </div>
```

edit: i added this javascript code and add id="myImageId' to every images but it makes only one image appears

```
function showImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById('myImageId');
    img.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: please add some codes

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: @aaalsubaie hmmm i wanna use java script.. i never used jQuery...

Comment: you need to add your javascript too...

Comment: @100rabh the problem is that!!! i don't know what should i add...

Comment: you said one click, one image appearing, how you did that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imagesRoot = document.getElementsByClassName("invisible-livingroom");
var images = imagesRoot[0].getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

in jQuery it is as simple as

```
$(".invisible-livingroom img").css("visibility", "hidden")
```

Comment: just worked magically! i had to use array, right? :D btw thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add class to all images say "hid_img"

```
<div class="invisible-livingroom">
    <img class="hid_img" src="IMAGE/w-clock.png" style="position:absolute; margin-left:1200px; filter:brightness(1.3);visibility:hidden; " />
    <img class="hid_img" src="IMAGE/w-stand.png" style="position:absolute; margin-left:1830px; margin-top:120px;filter:brightness(1.2);  height:800px; z-index:5; visibility:hidden;"/>
</div>
```

Then you can use following script

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hid_img");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Alternative, rather than hiding all your images, you can hide the entire div block as invisible and then display it on click.

```
<div id="lr" class="invisible-livingroom" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
```

Then you can set its visibility as

```
document.getElementsById("invisible-livingroom").style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to give an `id` for triggering element, separating/moving from `inline css` to separate `css file` and there will be so many ways to work with javascript.
Please review this one

```js
//declaring variables

var trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");

trigger.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName("invisible-livingroom")[0] //only try to get first array. elements could have same class name
  c.style.display = 'block';
})
```

```css
/*set default none*/

.invisible-livingroom {
  display: none;
}
/*for convenient only*/

img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<img id="trigger" src="IMAGE/w-click.png" />

<div class="invisible-livingroom">
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
  <img src="#"/>
</div>
```

Please visit this one:
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)